# Showing/Hiding fields in Google Forms

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, dom-events, google-forms

I've been searching for days for answers to this question, and even though I've found similar questions, I haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

I've set up a Google form, where my second question is a Yes/No radio button question. After that come several short/long answer questions.

What I would like to have is a script that on loading of the form (as soon as the user loads it), would hide **some** of these short/long answer questions by default. If the user selects "Yes" in the above mentioned 2nd question, those questions stay hidden. If the user selects "No", those questions would then show and they have to answer them.

How would that work using the script editor (I would think?) in my Google form?

Please bear in mind that I would like to set all showing questions as required, but not sure how that would work for the questions that are hidden.

Comment: You can check [PageBreakItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item) and [PageNavigationType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app.html#PageNavigationType) for implementing form go to a specific page based on an answer? See my [answer from the previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38378357/5995040)

Answer (score 0):

there is no solution to that question with a script (script can not modify form on the go) nevertheless you can simply do that using pages. (one specific page can be opened according to the answer of a question). The user will then see a page with some questions if he answered yes and an other page if he say no.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! What you suggested would work just as well, how would I go about doing that?