# Google Apps Scripts Form service

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, google-apps-script, google-apps

I want to know if there is any function in google app script form service for adding another choice to another different question when the answer of the first question is a certain choice

```
source.setTitle('Choose source')
source.setChoices([
source.createChoice('instagram.com'),
source.createChoice('facebook.com'),
source.createChoice('twitter.com'),
source.createChoice('facebook_instagram')])

medium.setTitle('Medium')
medium.setChoices([
medium.createChoice('CPC')])

var opcSource = source.getChoices();
var opc = opcSource[0].getValue();

if (opc === 'instagram.com'){
medium.createChoice('HELLOHELLO');
```

Comment: Put the question at the top. And made it normal text instead of being formated like a quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on your implementation. You can set the [**`createChoice(value, navigationItem)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue-navigationitem) and create a page where a certain choice item wil go.

> Creates a new choice with a page-navigation option that jumps to a given page-break item. This is equivalent to [**`createChoice(value, navigationType)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createChoice(String,PageNavigationType)) with **`navigationType`** set to **`FormApp.PageNavigationType.GO_TO_PAGE`**. Choices that use page navigation cannot be combined in the same item with choices that do not use page navigation.

You'll have to set multiple pages for you to achieve what you want. You can check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38378357/5995040) for code implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but you think there is no "Dinamic" way to make everything in the same page ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no dynamic way to do this